# Checkbox for Custom B2B App not showing up in iTunes connect

Tags: app-store, enterprise, b2b

I would like to bring an app to the Apple Store as a custom b2b app. The only problem is I don't have the option in my iTunes connect. Is this B2B program not available in Germany? I couldn't find any specific information about that. Maybe one of you has had the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, the check box just was not there. Make sure that within iTunesConnect you have agreed to the relevant contracts in under "Contracts, Tax, and Banking". Once you request and agree to those, the checkbox should appear.

Comment: and if you've had a valid "iOS Paid Applications" contract for years and you still don't see the checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

See this link - [Configuring a Custom B2B app (Optional)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/B2B.html)

It confirms the need for a Paid Applications contract.

Comment: I have also discovered that before you can submit to the B2B App Store, you have to have a valid VPP customer. You can't just put the app in the B2B store to test submission.